# Graphene mutation with list as input

Tags: graphql, graphene-python

I have a graphene mutation like this:

```py
class User(ObjectType):
    username = String()

class ImportUsers(Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        users = List(User)
    Output = List(User)

    @staticmethod
    def mutation(root, info, users):
        ...
```

But graphene gives me the following error: `AssertionError: Mutations.importUsers(users:) argument type must be Input Type but got: [User].`

How can I have a mutation in graphene which accepts a list of objects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was trying roughly the same thing as you did.

Figured out that custom input types should inherit from `graphene.InputObjectType` instead of `graphene.ObjectType`.

```py
class User(graphene.InputObjectType):  # <-- Changed to InputObjectType
    username = graphene.String()
```

So, having your `User` like this should solve the case.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah so, basically, you need to have this:

```
class User(graphene.ObjectType):
    username = graphene.String()

class ImportUsers(Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        users = graphene.List(User)

    Output = graphene.List(User)

    @staticmethod
    def mutation(root, info, users):
        ...
```

Graphene has a List type. Also, I don't know if it's just me or not, but I think you need to have graphene.(type), not just the type. I am working on something very similar right now to this, so hopefully you find or found your solution, and if you do, let me know how it went! Hopefully I helped xD. I am kinda new to all of this so ye

Comment: I get an error (listOfUsers:) argument type must be Input Type but got: [User].

Comment: That is because the class User must be of the type graphene.InputObjectType, so it could be used as an Argument in Mutation class.